# В чем проблема присваивания значения value тегу <option>?

Tags: javascript, html

В проекте нужно реализовать 2 связанных выпадающих списка, в которых содержимое второго списка заполняется в зависимости от выбора элемента в первом списки, за тем эти данные отправляются на сервер. Есть скрипт, которые реализует эту задачу, но возникла проблема. В переменную value записывается индекс элемента в массиве, а не само его значение. Где ошибка в коде?

```html
Название категории:
<select name="type" id="category" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
  <option value="Кальяны" selected>Кальяны</option>
  <option value="Напитки">Напитки</option>
  <option value="Еда">Еда</option>
</select>
Название подкатегории:
<select name="subtype" id="subcategory" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
  <script>
    let categories = {
      Еда: ["Салаты", "Пицца", "Пироги", "Блюда на углях", "Гарниры", "Мороженое"],
      Напитки: ["Лимонады", "Милкшейки", "Кофе", "Чайные напитки", "Алкогольные напитки"],
      Кальяны: ["Кальяны", "Коктейли", "Коктейль + Фруктовая чаша (апельсин)"]
    };
    let category = document.getElementById("category");
    let subcategory = document.querySelector("#subcategory");
    window.onload = selectCategory;
    category.onchange = selectCategory;

    function selectCategory(ev) {
      subcategory.innerHTML = "";
      let c = this.value || "Кальяны",
        o;
      for (let i = 0; i < categories[c].length; i++) {
        o = new Option(categories[c][i], categories[c][i]);
        subcategory.add(o);
      }
    }
  </script>
</select>
```

Comment: запустил, индексов в value не увидел

Comment: @PavelNazarian тут все хорошо, только в БД добавляется именно индекс товара

Comment: @Gonza1ess, значит проблема не тут, не так ли?

Answer (score 0):

> В переменную `value` записывается индекс элемента в массиве, а не само его значение. Где ошибка в коде?

Не вижу каких либо проблем, если выводить `value` при изменение `select`а, то выводится тоже значение, что и текст `option`.

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

[...selects].map(e => {
  e.addEventListener('change', e => console.info(e.target.value));
});
```

```html
Название категории:
<select name="type" id="category" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
  <option value="Кальяны" selected>Кальяны</option>
  <option value="Напитки">Напитки</option>
  <option value="Еда">Еда</option>
</select>
Название подкатегории:
<select name="subtype" id="subcategory" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
  <script>
    let categories = {
      Еда: ["Салаты", "Пицца", "Пироги", "Блюда на углях", "Гарниры", "Мороженое"],
      Напитки: ["Лимонады", "Милкшейки", "Кофе", "Чайные напитки", "Алкогольные напитки"],
      Кальяны: ["Кальяны", "Коктейли", "Коктейль + Фруктовая чаша (апельсин)"]
    };
    let category = document.getElementById("category");
    let subcategory = document.querySelector("#subcategory");
    window.onload = selectCategory;
    category.onchange = selectCategory;

    function selectCategory(ev) {
      subcategory.innerHTML = "";
      let c = this.value || "Кальяны",
        o;
      for (let i = 0; i < categories[c].length; i++) {
        o = new Option(categories[c][i], categories[c][i]);
        subcategory.add(o);
      }
    }
  </script>
</select>
```

Осмелюсь предположить, что проблема всё таки не в JS, а в обработчике на стороне сервера.

---

> точно не в JS? мы ж даже не видим, что он отправляет

Я не знаю как именно вы отправляете запрос на сервер, но если использовать [`form.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (JQ) или [аналог](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033425/7692602) на JS, то мы видим какой запрос ушёл

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

[...selects].map(e => {
  e.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e.target.name+': '+e.target.value));
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let query = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(e.target)).toString();
  console.log('POST: '+decodeURI(query));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  Название категории:
  <select name="type" id="category" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
    <option value="Кальяны" selected>Кальяны</option>
    <option value="Напитки">Напитки</option>
    <option value="Еда">Еда</option>
  </select>
  Название подкатегории:
  <select name="subtype" id="subcategory" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
    <script>
      let categories = {
        Еда: ["Салаты", "Пицца", "Пироги", "Блюда на углях", "Гарниры", "Мороженое"],
        Напитки: ["Лимонады", "Милкшейки", "Кофе", "Чайные напитки", "Алкогольные напитки"],
        Кальяны: ["Кальяны", "Коктейли", "Коктейль + Фруктовая чаша (апельсин)"]
      };
      let category = document.getElementById("category");
      let subcategory = document.querySelector("#subcategory");
      window.onload = selectCategory;
      category.onchange = selectCategory;

      function selectCategory(ev) {
        subcategory.innerHTML = "";
        let c = this.value || "Кальяны",
          o;
        for (let i = 0; i < categories[c].length; i++) {
          o = new Option(categories[c][i], categories[c][i]);
          subcategory.add(o);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="view query">
</form>
```

Comment: точно не в JS? мы ж даже не видим, что он отправляет

Comment: Возможно, я не вижу кода который отвечает за отправку данных на сервер, по нему можно было бы сказать. А насчёт `мы ж не видим` - дополнил ответ.